# Insert Automate Value if blank with sequence data

Tags: excel, vba, formula

If there is an empty cell in column C, take the data from column B starting from the beginning and import it in column D.

In D6 i write
`=OFFSET($B$4:$B$13,$C$2,0,1,1)`
and C2 i write
`=COUNTBLANK($C$4:$C$13)`
but is result App4

[image]

**Edit on Picture:**
[image]

Comment: Have you made any efforts yourself?

Comment: I tried to use offset and row as an aid, but keep following the number of rows

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to post your attempts as they may be remediable.

Comment: in D6 i write `=OFFSET($B$4:$B$13,$C$2,0,1,1)` and C2 i write `=COUNTBLANK($C$4:$C$13)`. but is result App4

Comment: You need a dynamic range otherwise you will just total up all the blanks in C (hence you get App4)  - see my answer for a rather different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF(C4="",INDEX($B$4:$B$13,SUMPRODUCT(--($D$3:D3<>""))+1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: how to pass and continue to the following data if a duplicate is found in column C

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

 Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, Counter As Long

    Counter = 4

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 4 To LastRow

            If .Range("C" & i).Value = "" Then
                .Range("D" & i).Value = .Range("B" & Counter).Value
                Counter = Counter + 1
            End If

        Next i

    End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: how to pass and continue to the following data if a duplicate is found in column C